# Kendo Vue Charts Native CDN Install Errors

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, kendo-ui

According to [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/charts/#toc-using-cdn) these are the files that need to be added

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-vue-charts@latest/dist/cdn/js/kendo-vue-charts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-vue-intl@latest/dist/cdn/js/kendo-vue-intl.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-drawing/dist/cdn/js/kendo-drawing.js"></script>
// Load the Kendo Default Theme
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-default@latest/dist/all.css">

    // Load the Kendo Bootstrap Theme
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap@latest/dist/all.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-default@latest/dist/all.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap@latest/dist/all.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-vue-charts@latest/dist/cdn/js/kendo-vue-charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-vue-intl@latest/dist/cdn/js/kendo-vue-intl.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-drawing/dist/cdn/js/kendo-drawing.js"></script>
```

The Error is

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'support') at Module. (kendo-vue-charts.js:1:28556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the script tags is wrong - we need to put the drawing script tag first, then the intl and last but not least the charts script.